# Как оптимизировать код php/mysql?

Tags: php, mysql

Как можно оптимизировать код, представленный ниже?

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file("xmlfiles/".$row['idzk'].".xml"); 

foreach ($xml->offer as $offer) {
    $id= 'internal-id';

    $import_obj = mysql_query("SELECT `internal-id` FROM object WHERE `internal-id`='$offer[$id]' ");

    if(mysql_fetch_array($import_obj)){
        echo '1';
    }
    else {
        echo '2';
    }
}
```

Comment: Если суть кода, проверить есть ли записи из XML в БД, то так и напишите в своем вопросе. Если их можно вывести пачкой, то тоже напишите об этом. Сколько у вас данных в этом XML 100 строк, или 100 тысяч? Сколько данных в базе? Есть ли индексы по полю выборки. И перейдите уже от использования `mysql_*` к чему-нибудь более современному. И при чем тут `phpmyadmin`

Comment: проверить есть ли id  в БД  где около 45000 строк, из XML берём id ?если есть то пишем 1, нет 2 (в результате вместо 1 мы обновляем данные в БД, 2 добавляем новые. Для простоты читабельности кода написал вывод строки со значение 1 или 2)

Comment: "И перейдите уже от использования mysql_* к чему-нибудь более современному"- это к чему?)

Comment: @ВикторВасильев к PDO, например.

Comment: посмотрите на инструкцию [`on duplicate key update`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-on-duplicate.html) но это в большей степени код упростит, а не повысит его эффективность.

Comment: по моему проще все разом залить во временную таблицу. А потом из нее уже обновить существующее и долить остатки. Инсерты во  временную склеить пачками по N штук в запросе.

Comment: То есть я правильно понимаю все залить на временную ()дополнительную таблицу)бд и после залива пустить автоматическое сравнение 2ух  баз, если повторяется обновить, если нет добавить новые данные?Так по вашему должно сократиться время обработки?

Comment: `в результате вместо 1 мы обновляем данные в БД, 2 добавляем новые` - **Это должно быть в вопросе!**

Comment: не 2х баз а двух таблиц. В целом на мой взгляд сократит. У вас будет меньше сгруппированных запросов на вставку с клиента вида `insert into tmp_data values (...), (...)`. Затем обновите имеющиеся `update data set value = (select value from tmp) where data.id = tmp.id`, и добавите отсутствующие `insert into data select * from tmp where id not in (select id from data)`. И индексы по полю сравнения  в обеих таблицах. Но собственно пока не попробуете, не узнаете. Если вы имортируете штук 100 записей, то разницы и не заметите.

Answer (score 6):

Проблема вашего кода в том, что вы делаете N запросов в базу там, где можно обойтись одним.

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file("xmlfiles/".$row['idzk'].".xml"); 
$offers = iterator_to_array($xml->offer);
if (count($offers) == 0) die('No ids');
$ids = array_map(function($offer){
  //return (int)$offer['internal-id'];
  return "'".mysql_real_escape_string($offer['internal-id'])."'";
}, $offers);

$in = implode(', ', $ids);
$sql = "select `internal-id` from `object` where `internal-id` IN ($in)";

$r = mysql_query($sql);
if (!$r) die(mysql_error());

$exists = [];
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($r, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
  $exists[$row['internal-id']] = true;
}
foreach ($offers as $offer) {
  if (isset($exists[$offer['internal-id']])) {
    echo "Найден {$offer['internal-id']}\n";
  } else {
    echo "Не найден {$offer['internal-id']}\n";
  }
}
```

*Если строк слишком много, можно отправлять пачками, скажем по 1000*

---

Для задачи из комментариев можно создать уникальный индекс по полю `internal-id` и воспользоваться конструкцией [on duplicate key update](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-on-duplicate.html):

```
$offers = iterator_to_array($xml->offer);
$values = array_map(function($offer) {
  // нужно экранировать значения здесь по необходимости
  //return '('.implode(', ', [(int)$offer['internal-id'], (int)$offer['a']]).')';
  return '('.implode(',', [
    "'".mysql_real_escape_string($offer['internal-id'])."'",
    int($offer['a']),
  ]).')';
}, $offers);
$values = implode(",\n", $values);

$sql = <<<SQL
INSERT INTO `object` (`internal-key`, `a`) 
VALUES $values 
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE 
  a = VALUES(a)
SQL;
```

---

[mysql_](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.mysql-connect.php)

> **Внимание:** Данное расширение устарело, начиная с версии PHP 5.5.0, и удалено в PHP 7.0.0. Используйте вместо него [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/ru/book.mysqli.php) или
>   [PDO_MySQL](http://php.net/manual/ru/ref.pdo-mysql.php). Смотрите также инструкцию [MySQL: выбор API](http://php.net/manual/ru/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) и
>   [соответствующий FAQ](http://php.net/manual/ru/faq.databases.php#faq.databases.mysql.deprecated) для получения более подробной информации.

Comment: На строчке if (!$r) die(mysql_error()); выводит ошибку You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ')' at line 1 php 5.4 ,  MySQL 5.5.52-1.el7

Comment: Для запросов SELECT, SHOW, DESCRIBE, EXPLAIN и других запросов, возвращающих результат из нескольких рядов, mysql_query() возвращает дескриптор результата запроса (resource), или FALSE в случае ошибки.

Comment: Понимаю, что синтаксическая ошибка, но не понимаю какая она может быть в строке  if (!$r) die(mysql_error());

Comment: Всё как вы написали сделал)

Comment: Если вы не выложите запрос, я не смогу вам помочь

Comment: if (count($xml->offer) == 0) die('No ids');


$ids= array_map(function($offer){return (string)$offer['internal-id'];}, $xml->offer);

$in = implode(', ', $ids);
$sql = "select `internal-id` from `object` where `internal-id` IN ($in)";

$r = mysql_query($sql);
if (!$r) die(mysql_error());

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/54071/discussion-between-vp-arth-and--).